# Left Join with Case Statement in Sql Server getting ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    Camp.ID, Inst.StartDate, Ctype.CampaignType,
    'Cert' + REPLACE(Ctype.CampaignType, ' ', '') AS CampaignType 
FROM 
    CertCampaign Camp
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        CASE WHEN CampaignType = 'CertAccounttoRole' THEN CertUserToAccount) t ON Inst.ID = t.InstanceId
LEFT JOIN  
    CertAccounttoRole ON Inst.ID = t.InstanceId
LEFT JOIN 
    CertCampaignType Ctype ON Ctype.ID = Camp.CampaignTypeId
LEFT JOIN 
    CertInstance Inst ON Inst.CampaignId = Camp.ID
```

Getting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Here is an end missing `then CertUserToAccount end )t`

Comment: This won't work even if you add `END` to the case statement. What exactly is your LEFT JOIN and CASE statement supposed to achieve?

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  The subquery is referencing a column `CampaignType` but has no `from` clause.

Comment: You can't choose tables in case statement, you can only return values there. You have to join your CertUserToAccount table as usual and use values from there only when required.

Comment: And even with these fixes, the query is still way off.  You are referencing table aliases before they are defined.  Could I suggest that you delete this question, write another that includes sample data, desired results, and you can include your attempt at a query.

Answer (score 1):

You need an END in your case stmt, you will also have to name that column:

```
LEFT JOIN(select case when CampaignType='CertAccounttoRole' 
                  then CertUserToAccount
             end as InstanceId )t  ON
Inst.ID=t.InstanceId
```

Comment: You are right, did not look that closely. I also suspect that CertUserToAccount is a table and that will never work.

Comment: Also see @GordonLinoff's comment to the question - missing `FROM` clause as well.